# Are events cause by CollaborativeList.move incorrect?

Tags: google-drive-realtime-api

The event.index in the VALUES_ADDED event seem to be taken straight out of the arguments passed to the CollaborativeList.move call, which can be incorrect.
For example,

```
list.move(0,0) // and
list.move(0,1)
```

are noops, and the first item in the list remains at index zero. However, the event.index in the resulting VALUES_ADDED event are 0 and 1 respectively.

Furthermore,

```
list.move(0,2)
```

results in the first item in the list end up at index 1. However, the event.index in the resulting event is 2.

Finally, for the noop cases, it seems better not to fire any event at all because there is no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the way it works is a bit confusing and the docs don't explain what/why the index values are what they are.

The index values are only really useful to update your local lists (local lists being an array of Objects that match/reference the Realtime Objects in your CollaborativeLists), so the indices are setup in a way that you can use them directly to modify your local list step-by-step. The realtime api doesnt make an attempt to send the minimum number of events, and if you move the same item multiple times the indices that are shown in the events do not necessarily reflect the final location of the item in the list.

Also useful is a quick bit from the Realtime API 'Handle Events' Developer Guide:

> All events for changes that occur within a compound operation are
>   emitted after all of the changes are applied to the model.

With these in mind, a quick example to illustrate what is actually happening and why it is happening this way:

```
beginCompoundOperation()
move(0, 3)
move(2, 0)
endCompoundOperation()
```

And with the move results:

```
beginCompoundOperation()
[A B C D]
move(0, 3)
[B C A D]
move(2, 0)
[A B C D]
endCompoundOperation()
```

In turn, the following events are fired:

```
VALUE_ADDED   : Index: 3, MovedFromIndex: 0
VALUE_REMOVED : Index: 0, MovedToIndex:   3
VALUE_ADDED   : Index: 0, MovedFromIndex: 2
VALUE_REMOVED : Index, 3, MovedToIndex:   0

(Note that the MovedFromIndx/MovedToIndex refer to the state of the list BEFORE the action in the event)
```

This is to allow your local list to make the following changes:

```
[A B C D]
VALUE_ADDED(3, 0)
[A B C A D]
VALUE_REMOVED(0, 3)
[B C A D]
VALUE_ADDED(0, 2)
[A B C A D]
VALUE_REMOVED(3, 0)
[A B C D]
```

So in your example, during the added event, the destination index takes into account that you are moving the item further into the list without removing it which would happen in the corresponding VALUES_REMOVED event.

Hope that is helpful!

And of course some code to test things out if you don't already have something like this:

move_test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Move Test</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/misc/move_test.js" type="application/javascript" ></script>
</head>
<body onload="onPageLoad()">
    <button onclick="runScenario()">Run Scenario</button>
</body>
```

move_test.js

```
var clientId = "<YOUR CLIENT ID HERE>";
var REALTIME_MIMETYPE = 'application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk';

// Everything interesting is at the bottom in the onDocLoaded function.

function createRealtimeFile(title, description, callback)
{
    console.log('Creating Drive Document');
    gapi.client.drive.files.insert({
        'resource':
        {
            'mimeType': REALTIME_MIMETYPE,
            'title': title,
            'description': description
        }
    }).execute(function (docInfo)
    {
        callback(docInfo, /*newDoc*/true);
    });
}

function openRealtimeFile(title, callback)
{
    gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', function ()
    {
        gapi.client.drive.files.list(
        {
            'q': 'title='+"'"+title+"' and 'me' in owners and trashed=false"
        }).execute(function (results)
        {
            if (!results.items || results.items.length === 0)
            {
                createRealtimeFile(title, /*DocDescription*/"", callback);
            }
            else
            {
                callback(results.items[0], /*newDoc*/false);
            }
        });
    });
}

function onPageLoad()
{
    var GScope =
    {
        Drive: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'
    };

    gapi.load('auth:client,drive-realtime,drive-share', function()
    {
        var handleAuthResult = function(authResult)
        {
            console.log('Requesting Drive Document');

            openRealtimeFile("TESTDOC__", function (docInfo, newDoc)
            {
                if (docInfo && docInfo.id)
                {
                    gapi.drive.realtime.load(docInfo.id, onDocLoaded, onDocInitialized, onDocLoadError);
                }
                else
                {
                    console.log('Unable to find realtime doc');
                    debugger;
                }
            });
        };

        gapi.auth.authorize(
        {
            client_id: clientId,
            scope: [ GScope.Drive ],
            immediate: false
        }, handleAuthResult);
    });
}

function onDocLoadError(e)
{
    console.log('Doc Load Error: ', e);
    findAndLoadDoc();
}

function onDocInitialized(model)
{
    console.log('Drive Document Initialized');

    var root = model.createMap();

    model.getRoot().set('docRoot', root);
}

function itemListen(item, listenerFn)
{
    if (listenerFn)
    {
        item.addEventListener(gapi.drive.realtime.EventType.OBJECT_CHANGED, listenerFn);
    }
}

function createItem(model, name, listenerFn)
{
    var map = model.createMap();
    var items = model.createList();

    map.set('items', items);
    map.set('name', name);

    if (listenerFn)
    {
        map.addEventListener(gapi.drive.realtime.EventType.OBJECT_CHANGED, listenerFn);
    }

    return map;
}

function addItem(parent, child)
{
    parent.get('items').push(child);
}

function removeItem(parent, index)
{
    parent.get('items').remove(index);
}

function moveItem(oldParent, oldIndex, newParent, newIndex)
{
    if (oldParent !== newParent)
    {
        oldParent.get('items').moveToList(oldIndex, newParent.get('items'), newIndex);
    }
    else
    {
        oldParent.get('items').move(oldIndex, newIndex);
    }
}

var scenarioRunning = false

function rootListen(event)
{
    if (!scenarioRunning)
    {
        return;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < event.events.length; ++i)
    {
        var ev = event.events[i];

        switch (event.events[i].type)
        {
            case gapi.drive.realtime.EventType.VALUES_ADDED:
                console.log('ADDED: ', ev);
                console.log('  Index: ', ev.index, ev.movedFromIndex);
                console.log('  List: ', ev.target.get(ev.index).get('name'));
                console.log('  Value: ', ev.values[0].get('name'));
                printList(root);
                break;
            case gapi.drive.realtime.EventType.VALUES_REMOVED:
                console.log('REMOVED: ', ev);
                console.log('  Index: ', ev.index, ev.movedToIndex);
                console.log('  List: ', ev.target.get(ev.index).get('name'));
                console.log('  Value: ', ev.values[0].get('name'));
                printList(root);
                break;
            default:
                debugger;
                break;
        }
    }
}

function printList(item)
{
    var list = item.get('items');

    var str = '[ ';

    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; ++i)
    {
        var entry = list.get(i);

        str += entry.get('name') + ' ';
    }

    str += ']';

    console.log(str);
}

var docModel;
var docRoot;
var root;
function onDocLoaded(doc)
{
    docModel = doc.getModel();
    docRoot = docModel.getRoot();

    window.__docRoot = docRoot;

    if (docRoot.has('root'))
    {
        docRoot.delete('root');
    }

    docRoot.set('root', createItem(docModel, 'root', rootListen));

    console.log('Document Loaded - Scenario Ready');

    root = docRoot.get('root');



    docModel.beginCompoundOperation();

    //      root
    //       |
    //  [A, B, C, D]

    var childA = createItem(docModel, 'childA');
    addItem(root, childA);

    var childB = createItem(docModel, 'childB');
    addItem(root, childB);

    var childC = createItem(docModel, 'childC');
    addItem(root, childC);

    var childD = createItem(docModel, 'childD');
    addItem(root, childD);

    docModel.endCompoundOperation();


    window.runScenario = function()
    {
        scenarioRunning = true;

        printList(root);

        console.log('---- Scenario Start ----');


        docModel.beginCompoundOperation();

        moveItem(root, 0, root, 3);
        moveItem(root, 2, root, 0);

        docModel.endCompoundOperation();


        console.log('---- Scenario Complete ----');

        printList(root);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that the add event came before the remove, which resolves the problem. Is there a reason you don't suppress any events that are noops anyway?

Also, it seems more natural in some way to have the remove event occur before the add event. Does the add event come first so that the index values don't have to change, or is there a different reason?

Comment: I'm just guessing, but it seems likely that the reason to not remove nop events is consistency and simplicity. There doesn't need to be logic to decide if events are nops or if they have an effect. In the end it is possible that the end result will be nops anyway (move(0, 2), move(2, 0) etc), so the responsibility is pushed to the consumer.

As far as add vs remove as the first event - having add come first allows you to distinguish between a 'move' and a 'remove' event easier. If the remove event came first, you wouldn't know if it was deleting from a list, or moving to a new spot'.